# Significato di "pedale" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Lucietta si era tolta il fazzoletto dalla testa e l’aveva intinto nell’olio, trasportandolo poi prudentemente dentro casa come un bambinello, per andare a torcerlo dentro il **pedale** vuoto. E cosí tutte, chi col grembiule chi col fazzoletto, chi dentro un secchio di rame chi di legno, affondavano e torcevano con energia.

Questo olio che cercano di raccogliere queste ragazze è olio di oliva.

Non capisco cosa significhi "pedale" in questo brano. Me lo sapreste spiegare? Le diverse accezioni per questo termine che ho trovato sui dizionari non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Può darsi che sia un vocabolo di uso regionale.

Infatti, questa stessa parola è apparsa precedentemente nel testo, in questo passo:

> Le mani di zí Uel sul tornio erano veloci e precise, i polpastrelli mezzo bruciacchiati accarezzavano con delicatezza i fianchi rotondi delle cuccume e delle brocche, come dio deve aver accarezzato quelli di Eva, il giorno della creazione. Impastava, modellava, infornava. Sfornava lucerne, **pedali** e cuccume. Le segnava coi cerchi concentrici che molto tempo prima servivano a far comunicare i vivi coi morti in una lingua che nessuno piú conosce. Terrecotte sottili e sonore, porose, umide, trasudanti. Cuccume che trattenevano la freschezza dell’acqua. Tanto perfette e sottili che un grido avrebbe potuto creparle.

E più avanti nel libro appare un'altra volta:

> Descriveva casa sua in maniera ogni volta diversa, spiegando com’era bella la naca per il fratello piccolo, il **pedale** pieno d’olio, la madia col pane, u giuston traboccante di grano, i boccali di salsicce sott’olio arrotolate come serpenti, senza preoccuparsi del fatto che tutti conoscevano benissimo la verità.

Quindi, sembra trattarsi di qualche tipo di recipiente per l'olio.

Comment: Sarà una voce dialettale per "pitale"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In questo [dizionario dialettale di Gallicchio](http://www.dizionariogallic.altervista.org/dialetto_gallicchiese/lessico_gallicchiese4.htm) ho trovato il significato e l'etimologia dal greco:

> ***pëdàlë***      
>   Grosso recipiente per l’olio, da **pitharion** diminuitivo di **pithos** (vaso)

Answer (score 0):

Secondo me in questo caso il significato di pedale è piuttosto quello di [pitale](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pitale/) cioè orinatoio, vaso da notte:

> **pitale** s. m. [dal gr. *πιϑάριον*, nome di recipiente], pop. – Vaso da
>   notte, orinale (ma talora distinto da questo, in quanto poteva servire
>   per depositarvi anche le feci): *i due comodini ... contenevano due p.
>   alti alti, stretti stretti, senza impugnatura, simili a due tubi, di
>   porcellana bianca a fiori rosa* (Moravia).

Infatti nel secondo passaggio da te inserito vengono descritti vari tipi di terrecotte che vengono create da zí Uel, lucerne, pitali e cuccume, ovvero bricchi.

Comment: Non so... può darsi che sia questo il significato, ma mi sembra un po' strano mettere l'olio di oliva in un pitale.